# In UML class diagram do I need to put association and dependency (both correct in my case) or dependency is stronger and I should put only that?

Tags: dependencies, uml, associations

I have a class that gets as parameter a specific type (association) but also this class have methods that gets as parameter this type (dependency). What is the type of relationship between my class and this type class?

a. Both, because association and dependency are different relations
b. dependency

Answer (score 1):

Once you have an association you implicitly have the dependency as well. Therefore no need to use both (though it would not be wrong).

So the answer would be **c**!